# How to write and read variables of type "double" using "MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew" in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine

I want to pass a double-type variable to an exe process provided by Unity3D using MemoryMappedFiles. I am successful to read the data in Unity process but in next level of my code I must pass this double variable to Vector3 of Unity which gets the float type.

I used this line to convert from double to float:

```
float omegafloat = Convert.ToSingle(omega);
```

the problem is that omega is a negative value around -0.004 but in Unity it is equal to +0.004! I wonder why this happened to my data?

Comment: How many bytes you are allocate for `MMF`? I never allocate less than 8, even if i need to write two bytes only. Float has size 4 bytes.

Comment: @Zam I used this line:   var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("memory", 1024);

Comment: 1KByte is enough. did you try to run my code?

Comment: Thank you @Zam and yes I tried this method and it works when all the code is implemented in the visual studio. when i put the data-reading part in the unity, the data is ruined in the Unity code! all the values are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `CreateMMF()` is your own function

```
float xIn = -0.0004F;
float xOut = 0;

MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = CreateMMF();

using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(0, 8))
{
    accessor.Write(0, xIn);
}

using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(0, 8))
{
    accessor.Read(0, out xOut);
}
```

xOut will be equal to -0.004F

Comment: no. 8 -- just size of block in bytes i need. in fact for `float` i need 4 bytes only, but i had some problem in past with "very small" MMF. you allocate 1024 bytes in your case, should works well.